# Writing to encrypted home directory from live USB

Tags: live-usb, backup, encryption, ecryptfs

I want to replace my entire home dir with a backup. While not logged in, so I don't break things. It's encrypted and the backup is (unencrypted) on an external SSD. I plan to boot from a live USB and copy the data over. What's the best way access the home dir on the laptop so I can write to it? From what I can tell, it should be `ecryptfs-recover-private` with the parameter `--rw`.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Encrypted home isn't used since many years ago. Only full drive with LUKS (and LVM) since then.

Comment: Oops, my mistake :( Thought It'd slip by unnoticed but I'm using Linux Mint. Most of the documentation I found for ecryptfs online was for Ubuntu.

Comment: this might help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188553/ddg#329639

Comment: Here is a step by step info how to mount the encrypted home folder with a usb boot device https://stackoverflow.com/a/67299494/4448410